# How do I correctly use a dynamic array in VBA to avoid the Expected Sub, Function or Property error?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compiler-errors, dynamic-arrays

Having trouble getting code to compile due to an array name throwing the Expected Sub, Function or Property error.

Function is to take two input ranges, one of strings and one of times.
Strings are task descriptions, first time in time range is the task start time, second time is the task end time. I want to put the task description and first pair of times in one array line. ie. [0,0,0] = [Drawing Review, 08:00, 10:00]

Checked that "TimeParse"" is a unique qualifier across all my functions and subs in the module (only have one module).
Tried defining the array statically and it still throws the same error. I'm not sure if this has something to do with me trying to test a function instead of a sub, but I've not run into this before working with arrays in other functions.

Code as follows;

````
Function Tasker()
    
    'Argument copy; TaskRange As Range, TimeRange As Range
    Dim TaskRange As Range
    Dim TimeRange As Range
    
    TaskRange = Range("B3:B4")
    TimeRange = Range("C3:C4")
    ArrayRows = TaskRange.Count
    
    Dim TimeParse(3, 1) As Double '<< even if the array is defined as ReDim TimeParse(3,ArrayRows) error persists
    
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    
    For Each Cell In TaskRange
        TimeParse [k,i] = Cell.Value '<<where the issue pops up, compiler hits "TimeParse" and is expecting something else.
        i = i + 1
    Next Cell
    
    For Each Cell In TimeRange
        If j Is Even Then
            k = 1
            TimeParse [k,j] = Cell.Value
            j = j + 1
        ElseIf j Is Odd Then
            k = 2
            TimeParse [k,j] = Cell.Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next Cell
        
    DoesTravelCount = False
    
End Function```
````

Comment: Change the `[]` to `()`.

Comment: `Is Even`, `Is Odd` are incorrect. Use `Mod`.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: I don't know if you have global variables. But your first line in every module should be `Option Explicit`. You should also have a look how do adress the ids of an array. Not in [] but in (). What is `Even` and `Odd`. Both are not declared in your given code.